# Is overriding Object.finalize() really bad?

Tags: java, virtual-machine, garbage-collection, open-close

The main two arguments against overriding `Object.finalize()` is that:

1. You don't get to decide when it's called.
2. It may not get called at all.

If I understand this correctly, I don't think those are good enough reasons to hate `Object.finalize()` so much.

1. It is up to the VM implementation and the GC to determine when the right time to deallocate an object is, not the developer. Why is it important to decide when `Object.finalize()` gets called?
2. Normally, and correct me if I'm wrong, the only time `Object.finalize()` wouldn't get called is when the application got terminated before the GC got a chance to run. However, the object got deallocated anyway when the application's process got terminated with it. So `Object.finalize()` didn't get called because it was not needed to be called. Why would the developer care?

Every time I'm using objects that I have to manually close (like file handles and connections), I get very frustrated. I have to be constantly checking if an object has an implementation of `close()`, and I'm sure I have missed a few calls to it at some points in the past. Why isn't it just simpler and safer to just leave it to the VM and GC to dispose of these objects by putting the `close()` implementation in `Object.finalize()`?

Comment: Also note: like many APIs from Java 1.0 era, thread semantics of `finalize()` is a bit messed up. If you ever implement it, make sure it's thread-safe with respect to all other methods on the same object.

Comment: When you hear people saying finalizers are bad, they don't mean your program will stop working if you have them; they mean the whole idea of finalization is pretty useless.

Comment: +1 to this question. Most of the answers below state that the resources like file descriptors are limited and that they should be manually collected.
The same was/is true about memory so if we accept some delay in memory collection, why not accepting it for file descriptors and/or other resources ?

Comment: Addressing your last paragraph, you can leave it to Java to handle closing things like file handles and connections with very little effort on your part. Use the try-with-resources block - it's mentioned a few other times already in answers and comments, but I think it's worth putting here. The Oracle tutorial for this is found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 47):

In my experience, there is ***one and only one*** reason for overriding `Object.finalize()`, but it is ***a very good reason***:

> To place error logging code in `finalize()` which notifies you if you ever
>   forget to invoke `close()`.

Static analysis can only catch omissions in trivial usage scenarios, and the compiler warnings mentioned in another answer have such a simplistic view of things that you actually have to disable them in order to get anything non-trivial done.  (I have far more warnings enabled than any other programmer that I know of or ever heard of, but I don't have stupid warnings enabled.)

Finalization might seem to be a good mechanism for making sure that resources do not go undisposed, but most people see it in a completely wrong way: they think of it as an alternate fallback mechanism, a "second chance" safeguard which will automagically save the day by disposing of the resources that they forgot. ***This is dead wrong***. There must be only one way of doing any given thing: either you always close everything, or finalization always closes everything.  But since finalization is unreliable, finalization cannot be it.

So, there is this scheme which I call *Mandatory Disposal*, and it stipulates that the programmer is responsible for **always explicitly closing everything** which implements `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable`.  (The try-with-resources statement still counts as explicit closing.)  Of course, the programmer may forget, so that's where finalization comes into play, but *not* as a magic fairy which will magically make things right in the end: If finalization discovers that `close()` was not invoked, it does *not* attempt to invoke it, precisely because there will (with mathematical certainty) be hordes of n00b programmers who will rely on it to do the job that they were too lazy or too absent minded to do.  So, with mandatory disposal, when finalization discovers that `close()` was not invoked, it logs a bright red error message, telling the programmer with big fat all-capital letters to fix his s-- er, his stuff.

As an additional benefit, [rumor has it](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer2.shtml) that "the JVM will ignore a trivial finalize() method (e.g. one which just returns without doing anything, like the one defined in the Object class)", so with mandatory disposal you can **avoid all finalization overhead in your entire system** ([see alip's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/288753/41811) for information on how terrible this overhead is) by coding your `finalize()` method like this:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
{
    if( Global.DEBUG && !closed )
    {
        Log.Error( "FORGOT TO CLOSE THIS!" );
    }
    //super.finalize(); see alip's comment on why this should not be invoked.
}
```

The idea behind this is that `Global.DEBUG` is a `static final` variable whose value is known at compilation time, so if it is `false` then the compiler will not emit any code at all for the entire `if` statement, which will make this a *trivial* (empty) finalizer, which in turn means that your class will be treated as if it does not have a finalizer.  (In C# this would be done with a nice `#if DEBUG` block, but what can we do, this is java, where we pay apparent simplicity in the code with additional overhead in the brain.)

More about Mandatory Disposal, with additional discussion about disposing of resources in dot Net, here: [michael.gr: Mandatory disposal vs. the "Dispose-disposing" abomination](http://blog.michael.gr/2015/03/on-dispose-bool-disposing-abomination.html)

Comment: Would you please demonstrate how you log in the `finalize` method? I'm not a Java developer, but I'm very interested in the concept.

Comment: @Songo For logging in general, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950557/good-examples-using-java-util-logging .  For logging in the finalizer, there's no magic to it.  just something like, if( notClosed ) Log.Warn( "You forgot to...") .  Presumably you can check if you remembered to close, since you probably null, set, or zero something when you close so it's safe to call close more than once.

Comment: @PatrickM thanks for answering this. I do, however, take issue with calling `close()` more than once. Of course you have to keep track of whether `close()` has been invoked, (and having a `boolean closed` member is far more elegant than relying on nulled or zeroed stuff,) and what this allows you to do then is to **assert that `close()` is never called twice.**

Comment: @MikeNakis Don't forget, Closeable is defined as doing nothing if called a second time: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html .  I admit that I've sometimes logged a warning when my classes are closed twice, but technically you're not even supposed to do that.  Technically though, calling .close() on Closable more than once is perfectly valid.

Comment: @PatrickM You are right, but instead of "technically" I would rather say "officially".  That's the official line of the creators of java, it does not mean that it is technically the best option, at least in a theoretical discussion in which we are trying to find what is (what could be) best. They are known to have made a few bad decisions in the direction of the **soft error** doctrine, for example `Map.put()`, which will either add or replace, supposedly to make things easier for the programmer, while in actuality they are making it a lot easier to make mistakes.  **Hard Error** For The Win!

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm willing to agree that Map should have an insertAndThrowIfExists, but like Closable, the user can't change that interface.  In general, if you implement an interface, you should follow the interface.  For instance, you shouldn't create something that implements java.util.Map, but throws (a RuntimeException) when you call put() with duplicate input.  Not following the interface will tend to really screw with anyone who re-uses your code.

Comment: @PatrickM OK, I agree with you.  I am choosing kind of a rogue path in this respect.

Comment: This strategy can cause production downtime if there ever is a leak/bug. Unacceptable. Logging is good, but also close.

Comment: @usr it all boils down to whether you trust your testing or you don't trust your testing.  If you don't trust your testing, sure, go ahead and suffer the finalization overhead to **also** `close()`, just in case.  I believe that if my testing is not to be trusted, then I better not release the system to production.

Comment: It appears that you are able to never put bugs into production. In that case I agree that a safety net is not required...

Comment: @usr Oh, how can I argue with irony?  In my experience bugs make it to production mainly because they were not tested for, or due to various other reasons, (for example, incompatibilities between production and development environment,) but generally things that are sufficiently tested do not cause bugs on production. In any case, we do not have much of a disagreement here: if I was delivering a system of medium to high criticality, I would, like you, be taking additional measures besides testing.

Comment: @Mike, for the `if( Global.DEBUG && ...` construct to work so the JVM will ignore the `finalize()` method as trivial, `Global.DEBUG` must be set at compilation time (as opposed to injected etc.) so what follows will be dead code. The call to `super.finalize()` outside the if block is also enough for the JVM to treat it as non-trivial (regardless of the value of `Global.DEBUG`, at least on HotSpot 1.8) even if also the super class's `#finalize()` is trivial!

Comment: @alip Thanks for pointing out these two issues.  Regarding Global.DEBUG, I am afraid you are right. I amended my answer to that effect. That's java for you: there is nothing we can do but modify source files in order to produce a decent debug build.

Comment: @alip Regarding `super.finalize()`, I am tempted to believe you, but are you sure? Do you have proof?  Anyway, if that is the case, the solution is simple: if you know that the super's `finalize()` is trivial, don't call it.  I added a note about that in the code.

Comment: @Mike I'm afraid that's the case. I tested it with (a slightly modified version) of the test in the [article you linked to](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer2.shtml), and verbose GC output (together with surprisingly poor performance) confirm that the objects are copied to survivor/old generation space and need full heap GC to get rid of.

Comment: @alip okay, I do not have the time to check this, so I will take your word for it.  I amended my answer.  Additional confirmations by other readers would be appreciated.

Comment: @MikeNakis what do you think of JNA's usage of finalize() to call `peer.free()`, which calls C's `delete` freeing the native memory assoicated with your fancy java object? Is this usage incorrect? I think this usage is probably exactly correct; you're extending javas core memory collection facility to include collecting some additional memory. Thus I don't think its fair to say the _only_ use case is for logging, I think it is fair to say that using finalize() to clean up file streams and database connections (~99% of java use cases?) _is not a good idea_.

Comment: @Groostav I don't know of any `peer.free()`, so instead let's talk about `com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.finalize()` invoking `dispose()` on itself.

Comment: There is no difference between this, and `FileInputStream` using `finalize()` to invoke `close()` on itself.  In both cases, what happens in the end, is that some native resource is freed.  If you are lucky.

Comment: So, **yes, it is wrong.**  Or, **it is wrong to do only that**. You should try to always invoke `close()` or `dispose()` on these objects, and their `finalize()` method should be giving out big fat bright purple bold italic warnings if it ever finds out that you forgot to invoke `close()`.  So that `finalize()` is ***never*** necessary for your program's correctness.  Because it cannot be guaranteed that it will be invoked.

Comment: You're looking at a different object. From my understanding the `Library` object is itself a proxy for a `dll` or `so`. So if you want to release a DLL from memory of course you would call `library.dispose()` --it would be insane not to. No, my suggestion was about `com.sun.jna.Memory.finalize()`. `Memory` is your native-surrogate-providing SPI (base class) when you use JNA. In our dealings with the API, when we acquire an object from native code, its written as a java POJO `extends Memory`, and we do _not_ explicitly `dispose()` them, we let the GC do it for us. I believe this is as intended.

Comment: @Groostav okay, I found it.  (I have jna-4.1.0)  Same thing.  `com.sun.jna.Memory.finalize()` invokes `dispose()` on itself, and `dispose()` invokes `free()`. (Without even checking if `peer` is already 0, I suppose `free()` checks for that.)  What I am suggesting here with ***Mandatory Disposal*** is that you should always make sure to invoke `dispose()` yourself, and that this `finalize()` should sound an alarm if it does not find `peer` to be 0.  It may go ahead and invoke `free()` anyway, as @usr suggested, but the alarm should be sounded.

Comment: What is often overlooked, is the risk of earlier-than-expected collection of objects which makes freeing resources in the finalizer a very dangerous action. Prior to Java 9, the only way to be sure that a finalizer doesn’t close the resource while it is still in use, is to synchronize on the object, in both, the finalizer and the method(s) using the resource. That’s why it works in `java.io`. If that kind of thread safety wasn’t on the wish list, it adds to the overhead induced by `finalize()`…

Comment: `"There must be only one way of doing any given thing"` Why?..... Also how is finalization "unreliable"? Didn't the OP already go over the fact that the only case it isn't called is when the VM shuts down before it's called, in which case no one cares? What am I missing?

Comment: @Kröw there must be only one way of doing any given thing because otherwise complexity goes through the roof, and code can even become treacherously misleading.  I am surprised I have even spell this out.  It is as fundamental as "why must variables be given meaningful names".

Comment: @Kröw Finalization is unreliable because the documentation says so. Do not disregard the documentation based on your empirical observations; if that path you go, only pain you will find.

Comment: @Kröw Case in point, various VMs use various strategies, and one of them (popular on desktop apps) is to postpone all garbage collection until the VM actually starts to run out of memory. If you allow a very scarce resource to be controlled by finalization, then on a machine with a lot of memory the VM will only start triggering garbage collection a long time after it has ran out of that scarce resource.  So, your app will start randomly dying out there in the field at some unpredictable point in time in the future.  Nice, eh?

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm sorry to say but your first comment was stupid; complexity doesn't go "through the roof" if one thing can be done in just two ways. Furthermore, if a developer can't handle something that can be done in two ways instead of one, he/she needs to be fired. As for your second comment, you've strayed further from answering my question. Now I ask, where in the documentation does it say that? I think you might want to reread the docs or explain what you meant. Also, just for your further reference, something doesn't become unreliable *because* the documentation says it is,

Comment: it becomes unreliable for whatever reason it's unreliable, and the documentation makes us aware of that. Your third comment gave a perfect answer to that though, so thank you for it! That's an excellent reason why not to use finalize, especially in the way I was planning to. Fortunately, I know which JVM I'll be exporting to, so I'll be able to account for the specifics of finalization that it provides.

Answer (score 27):

> Every time I'm using objects that I have to manually close (like file handles and connections), I get very frustrated. [...] Why isn't it just simpler and safer to just leave it to the VM and GC to dispose of these objects by putting the `close()` implementation in `Object.finalize()`?

Because file handles & connections (that is, [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) on Linux & POSIX systems) are quite a scarce resource (you might be limited to 256 of them on some systems, or to 16384 on some others; see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)). There is no guarantee that the GC will be called enough often (or at the right time) to avoid exhausting such limited resources. And if the GC is not called enough (or the finalization are not run at the right time) you'll be reaching that (possibly low) limit.

Finalization is a "best effort" thing in the JVM. It might not be called, or be called quite late... In particular, if you have a lot of RAM or if your program don't allocate a lot of objects (or if most of them die before being forwarded to some old enough generation by a copying generational GC), the GC could be called quite rarely, and the finalizations might not run very often (or even might not run at all).

So `close` file descriptors explicitly, if possible. If you are afraid of leaking them, use finalization as an extra measure, not as the main one.

Comment: I would add that closing a stream to a file or socket normally flushes it. Leaving streams open needlessly increases the risk of data loss if the power goes out, a connection drops (this is also a risk for files accessed across a network), etc.

Comment: Actually, while the number of filedescriptors allowed might be low, that's not the *really* sticky point, because one *could* use that as a signal for the GC at least. The really problematic thing it's a) completely intransparent to the GC how much non-GC-managed resources hang on it, and b) many of those resources are unique, so others will might be blocked or denied.

Comment: And if you leave a file open it might interfere with someone else using it.  (Windows 8 XPS viewer, I'm looking at you!)

Comment: _"If you are afraid of leaking [file descriptors], use finalization as an extra measure, not as the main one."_ This statement sounds fishy to me. If you design your code well, should you really introduce redundant code that spreads cleanup over multiple places?

Comment: I have 30+years of developer experience (and a PhD in computer science) and I cannot claim to always design my code well. Can you?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Your point being that in an ideal world, yes, redundancy is bad, but in practice, where you can not foresee all relevant aspects, better be safe than sorry?

Comment: That is my point, yes...

Comment: @mucaho if you write the code well, the cleanup occurs in a single place and is called by `close` and `finalize` - there is no issue here.

Answer (score 13):

Look at the matter this way: you should only be writing code that is (a) correct (otherwise your program is plain wrong) and (b) necessary (otherwise your code is too large, which means more RAM necessary, more cycles spent on useless things, more effort to understand it, more time spent on maintaining it etc. etc.)

Now consider what it is that you want done in a finalizer. *Either* it's necessary. In that case you can't put it into a finalizer, because you don't know if it will be called. That's not good enough. *Or* it it not necessary - then you shouldn't be writing it in the first place! Either way, putting it into the finalizer is the wrong choice.

(Note that the examples you name, like closing file streams, *look* as if they're not really necessary, but they are. It's just that until you hit the limit for open file handles on your system, you won't *notice* that your code is incorrect. But that limit is a feature of the operating system and is therefore even more unpredictable than the JVM's policy for finalizers, so it really, really **is** important that you don't waste file handles.)

Comment: If I'm only supposed to write code that is "necessary" then should I avoid all of the styling in all my GUI applications? Surely none of it is necessary; the GUIs will work just fine without styling, they'll just look horrid. About the finalizer, it can be necessary to do something, but still ok to put it in a finalizer, since the finalizer will be called during object GC, if at all. If you need to close a resource, *specifically* when it's ready for garbage collection, then a finalizer is optimal. Either the program terminates releasing your resource or the finalizer is called.

Comment: If I have a RAM heavy, expensive-to-create, closeable object and I decide to reference it weakly, so that it can be cleared when not needed, then I could use `finalize()` to close it in case a gc cycle really needs to free up RAM. Otherwise, I'd keep the object in RAM instead of having to regenerate and close it every time I need to use it. Sure, resources it opens won't be freed until the object is GCed, whenever that may be, but I may not need to guarantee that my resources be freed at a certain time.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to why leaving it to the finalizer to release resources is generally a bad idea, finalizeable objects come with performance overhead.

From *Java theory and practice: Garbage collection and performance* (Brian Goetz), [Finalizers are not your friend](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp01274/):

> Objects with finalizers (those that have a non-trivial finalize() method) have significant overhead compared to objects without finalizers, and should be used sparingly. Finalizeable objects are both slower to allocate and slower to collect. At allocation time, the JVM must register any finalizeable objects with the garbage collector, and (at least in the HotSpot JVM implementation) finalizeable objects must follow a slower allocation path than most other objects. Similarly, finalizeable objects are slower to collect, too. It takes at least two garbage collection cycles (in the best case) before a finalizeable object can be reclaimed, and the garbage collector has to do extra work to invoke the finalizer. The result is more time spent allocating and collecting objects and more pressure on the garbage collector, because the memory used by unreachable finalizeable objects is retained longer. Combine that with the fact that finalizers are not guaranteed to run in any predictable timeframe, or even at all, and you can see that there are relatively few situations for which finalization is the right tool to use.

Comment: Excellent point.  See [my answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/288724/41811) which provides a means of avoiding the performance overhead of `finalize()`.

Answer (score 7):

One of the biggest reasons not to rely of finalizers is that most of the resources one might be tempted to clean up in the finalizer are very limited. The garbage collector only runs every so often, since traversing references to determine whether or not something can be released is expensive. This means that it could 'be a while' before your objects actually get destroyed. If you have a lot of objects opening up short-lived database connections, for example, leaving the finalizers to clean up these connections could exhaust your connection pool while it waits for the garbage collector to finally run and free up finished connections. Then, because of the wait, you wind up with a large backlog of queued up requests, which quickly exhaust the connection pool again. It's a cycle that will quickly put your application into a crippled state of operation.

Additionally, the use of try-with-resources makes closing 'closable' objects on completion easy to do. If you are not familiar with this construct, I suggest you check it out:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 7):

My (least) favourite reason for avoiding `Object.finalize` is not that objects might get finalized after you expect it, but they can get finalized *before* you might expect it. The problem is not that an object that is still in scope can be finalized before the scope is exited if Java decides it is no-longer reachable.

```
void test() {
   HasFinalize myObject = ...;
   OutputStream os = myObject.stream;

   // myObject is no-longer reachable at this point, 
   // even though it is in scope. But objects are finalized
   // based on reachability.
   // And since finalization is on another thread, it 
   // could happen before or in the middle of the write .. 
   // closing the stream and causing much fun.
   os.write("Hello World");
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376768/can-java-finalize-an-object-when-it-is-still-in-scope) for more details.
Even more fun is that this decision might only be made after hot-spot optimisation kicks in, making this painful to debug.

Comment: The thing is that `HasFinalize.stream` should itself be a separately finalizable object.  That is, the finalization of `HasFinalize` shouldn't finalize or try to clean-up `stream`.  Or if it should, then it should make `stream` inaccessible.

Comment: [It’s even worse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488)

Answer (score 4):

> I have to be constantly checking if an object has an implementation of close(), and I'm sure I have missed a few calls to it at some points in the past.

In Eclipse, I get a warning whenever I forget to close something that implements `Closeable`/`AutoCloseable`. I'm not sure if that's an Eclipse thing or if it's part of the official compiler, but you might look into using similar static analysis tools to help you there. FindBugs, for example, can probably help you check whether you've forgotten to close a resource.

Comment: Good idea mentioning `AutoCloseable`. It makes it brain-dead-easy to manage resources with try-with-resources. This nullifies several of the arguments in the question.

Answer (score 2):

To your first question:

> It is up to the VM implementation and the GC to determine when the right time to deallocate an object is, not the developer. Why is it important to decide when `Object.finalize()` gets called?

Well, the JVM will determine, when it is a good point to reclaim the storage that has been allocated for an object. This is not necessarily the time when the resource clean up, you want to perform in `finalize()`, should happen. This is illustrated in the [“finalize() called on strongly reachable object in Java 8”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488) question on SO. There, a `close()` method has been called by a `finalize()` method, while an attempt to read from the stream by the same object is still pending. So besides the well-known possibility that `finalize()` gets called way to late there is the possibility that it gets called too early.

The premise of your second question:

> Normally, and correct me if I'm wrong, the only time `Object.finalize()` wouldn't get called is when the application got terminated before the GC got a chance to run.

is simply wrong. There is no requirement for a JVM to support finalization at all. Well, it’s not completely wrong as you could still interpret it as “the application got terminated before finalization took place”, assuming that your application will ever terminate.

But note the small difference between “GC” of your original statement and the term “finalization”. Garbage collection is distinct to finalization. Once the memory management detects that an object is unreachable, it may simply reclaim its space, if either, it doesn’t have a special `finalize()` method or finalization is simply unsupported, or it may enqueue the object for finalization. Thus, the completion of a garbage collection cycle does not imply that finalizers are executed. That may happen at a later time, when the queue is processed, or never at all.

This point is also the reason why even on JVMs with finalization support, relying on it for resource cleanup is dangerous. Garbage collection is part of the memory management and hence triggered by memory needs. It’s possible that garbage collection never runs because there is enough memory during the whole runtime (well, that still fits into the “the application got terminated before the GC got a chance to run” description, somehow). It’s also possible that the GC does run but afterwards, there is enough memory reclaimed, so the finalizer queue is not processed.

In other words, native resources managed this way are still an alien to the memory management. While it is guaranteed that an `OutOfMemoryError` is only thrown after sufficient attempts to free memory, that does not apply to native resources and finalization. It is possible that opening a file fails due to insufficient resources while the finalization queue is full of objects which could free these resources, if the finalizer ever ran…